# AngularJS and Webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack to build my `AngularJS` application.

There's a common way to define a new module that depends on `angular-animate` in `AngularJS`:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["angular-animate"]);
```

When using `Webpack`, I have to make a require first to have this module available:

```
var angularAnimate = reqiure("angular-animate");
```

And now I've found an [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-animate) and I don't understand how it works:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-animate')]);
```

It requires `angular-animate` module and uses the result as a dependency. But as far as I know, [module dependencies should be an array of strings](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module).

Could you clarify please, how does [the example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-animate) work?

Comment: this is `[require('angular-animate')]` array, only with one element

Comment: @MatejMarconak, I've already discovered the mechanism. Please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked throwgh `angular-animate` module.

It contains `package.json` with `main` section that targets to `index.js`.

And `index.js` is a simple `CommonJS` module that first call

```
require('./angular-animate');
```

and then exports a string with `angular-animate` module name:

```
module.exports = 'ngAnimate';
```

So simple.